# How to merge two datasourcemodel using mvvm in swift

Tags: ios, swift, merge, tableview, alamofire

I have two datasource model.I am doing in mvvm.

My datasourcemodel is as below.

```
class QuestionDataSourceModel: NSObject {

    var dataListArray:Array<QuestionListModel>? = []

    var list:Array<OptionsModel>? = []


    init(array :Array<[String:Any]>?) {
        super.init()



        var newArray:Array<[String:Any]> = []
        if array == nil{

            // newArray = self.getJsonDataStored22()
        }
        else{
            newArray = array!

        }

        var datalist:Array<QuestionListModel> = []
        for dict in newArray{

            let model = QuestionListModel(dictionary: dict)

            datalist.append(model)
        }
        self.dataListArray = datalist
        print(self.dataListArray)
    }

}
```

the above is first datasourcemodel.

Next datasourcemodel is as below.

```
class DummyDataSourceModel: NSObject {
    var dataListArray:Array<DummyDataModel>? = []

    var list:Array<DummyDataModel>? = []


    init(array :Array<[String:Any]>?) {
        super.init()



        var newArray:Array<[String:Any]> = []
        if array == nil{

            // newArray = self.getJsonDataStored22()
        }
        else{
            newArray = array!

        }

        var datalist:Array<DummyDataModel> = []
        for dict in newArray{

            let model = DummyDataModel(dictionary: dict)

            datalist.append(model)
        }
        self.dataListArray = datalist
        print(self.dataListArray)
    }

}
```

In my view controller :-

```
 questionViewModel.loadData { (isSuccess) in


            if(isSuccess == true)
            {
                let sec = self.questionViewModel.numberOfSections()
                for _ in 0..<sec
                {


                    self.questionViewModel.answers1.add("")
                    self.questionViewModel.questions1.add("")
                    self.questionViewModel.questionlist1.add("")


                }
            //questionViewModel.numberOfSections()


                  self.activityindicator.stopAnimating()
                  self.activityindicator.isHidden = true
                   self.tableview.refreshControl = refreshControl
               self.tableview .allowsMultipleSelection = false

                self.tableview.reloadData()


              //  self.questionViewModel.loadData2{ (isSuccess) in

                   self.dummyDataViewModel.loadData1{ (isSuccess) in


                    if(isSuccess == true)
                    {

                        print(self.questionViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)
                        self.questionViewModel.totaldata()
                        self.tableview2.allowsMultipleSelection = false
                        self.tableview2.reloadData()


                    }
                    else{

                     self.viewDidLoad()

                    }


                }



            }
            else{


                self.activityindicator.stopAnimating()

                self.activityindicator.isHidden = true


                let controller = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet Detected", message: "This app requires an Internet connection", preferredStyle: .alert)
                // Create the actions
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
                    UIAlertAction in
                    NSLog("OK Pressed")


                    self.viewDidLoad()


                }
                controller.addAction(okAction)


                self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

                        }
        }
```

MY QuestionViewModel:-

```
 func loadFromWebserviceData(completion :@escaping (QuestionDataSourceModel?) -> ()){


        Alamofire.request("http://www.example.com").validate(statusCode: 200..<300).validate(contentType: ["application/json"]).responseJSON{ response in

            let status = response.response?.statusCode
            print("STATUS \(status)")

            print(response)

            switch response.result{

            case .success(let data):
                print("success",data)

                let result = response.result

                print(result)

                if  let wholedata = result.value as? [String:Any]{

                    print(wholedata)


                    if  let data = wholedata["data"] as? Array<[String:Any]>{

                        print(data)
                        print(response)

                        for question in data {

                            let typebutton = question["button_type"] as? String
                            print(typebutton)
                            self.type = typebutton

                            let options = question["options"] as! [String]

                         //   self.dataListArray1 = [options]
                            self.tableArray.append(options)
                           // self.savedataforoptions(completion: <#T##(NH_OptionslistDataSourceModel?) -> ()#>)

                            self.no = options.count
                        }

                        print(self.tableArray)


                        let newDataSource:QuestionDataSourceModel = QuestionDataSourceModel(array: data)

                        completion(newDataSource)

                    }

                }


            case .failure(let encodingError ):
                print(encodingError)

                //  if response.response?.statusCode == 404{

                print(encodingError.localizedDescription)

                completion(nil)

            }

        }}

  func loadData(completion :@escaping (_ isSucess:Bool) -> ()){


        loadFromWebserviceData { (newDataSourceModel) in

            if(newDataSourceModel != nil)
            {

                self.datasourceModel = newDataSourceModel!
                completion(true)

            }
            else{
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

my dummyViewModel is below:-

```
 func loadFromDummyData(completion :@escaping (DummyDataSourceModel?) -> ()){


        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jsonData", ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let jsonData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)

                do {
                    let jsonResult: NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary


                    if let people  = jsonResult["data"] as? Array<[String:Any]> {
                        //  self.dict = people



                        for person in people {

                            let options = person["options"] as! [String]


                            self.tableArray.append(options)



                            let name = person ["question"] as! String

                                                      self.tableArray.append(options)
                        }
                        let newDataSource:DummyDataSourceModel = DummyDataSourceModel(array: people)

                        completion(newDataSource)


                    }



                } catch {}
            } catch {}
        }

    }

    func loadData1(completion :@escaping (_ isSucess:Bool) -> ()){


        loadFromDummyData{ (newDataSourceModel) in

            if(newDataSourceModel != nil)
            {

                self.datasourceModel = newDataSourceModel!
                completion(true)

            }
            else{
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

Now i need to merge this two datasourceModel.

I am using tableview to display the data .

So first i need to display the data from the JSON.then below i need to display the data from the json.file.So how to merge this two datasourcemodel.

First the data from JSON has 10 sections.
In json.file it has 3 sections.So total 13 sections .So i need to display the 13 sections together in the tableview.How to do?

This the json.file data:-

```
{
    "data":[
              {
              "question": "Gender",
              "options": ["Male","Female"],
            "button_type":"2"

              },
              {
              "question": "How old are you",
              "options": ["Under 18","Age 18 to 24","Age 25 to 40","Age 41 to 60","Above 60"],
              "button_type":"2"
             },

             {
                "button_type":"2",
               "question": "I am filling the Questionnaire for?",
               "options": ["Myself","Mychild","Partner","Others"]

              }
              ]


}
```

And same format forJSON from api.

```
{
        "data":[
                  {
                  "question": "Gender",
                  "options": ["Male","Female"],
                "button_type":"2"

                  },
                  {
                  "question": "How old are you",
                  "options": ["Under 18","Age 18 to 24","Age 25 to 40","Age 41 to 60","Above 60"],
                  "button_type":"2"
                 },

                 {
                    "button_type":"2",
                   "question": "I am filling the Questionnaire for?",
                   "options": ["Myself","Mychild","Partner","Others"]

                  }
                  ]


    }
```

Comment: How to merge two datasourceModels?

Comment: Share your data models?

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas i have added my code.Please check.So how to solve here?

Comment: Why did you create two models for same JSON pattern?

Comment: You should use same model for both jsons. Because OOP says bind your common data in a single class and both json have everything in common.

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas the keys are same.But values are different in the json From the api.tHEN HOW TO DO?

Comment: because your keys are same it means variables/objects in your class will also be same then you do not need to create two separate classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
class OptionsModel: NSObject {
    var options: [String]?
    var question: String?
    var button_type: String?
}


class OptionsViewModel: NSObject {
    var optionList: Array<OptionsModel>?

    func callApi() { 
         yourApiCall() { webResponseArray in
              for res in webResponseArray {
                  let model = OptionsModel(json: res)
                  if optionList == nil {
                      optionList = [OptionsModel]()//Initialize Array if not initialized
                  }
                  optionList.append(model)// You are appending Option getting from web Api Response
              }
              //After Completely fetching all models from webResponseArray you should load Data from Local JSON
              loadLocalJSON()//After loading Data from Web You are loading Data from local JSON.
         }
    }
    func loadLocalJSON() {
         let localJsonArray = someMethodToLoadJsonFromLocalFileAndReturnsJSON()
         for json in localJsonArray {
              let model = OptionsModel(json: json)
              if optionList == nil {
                  optionList = [OptionsModel]()//Initialize Array if not initialized
              }
              optionList.append(model)// You are appending Option getting from Local JSON
         }
         //Now you have a single Array containing all local and remote option models.
    }
}
```